# Generating Documentation for complicated project structure

Tags: doxygen

I have a C project that is structured like so:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── c_kernels
│   ├── cuda
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── kernel_interface.h
│   │   └── kernel.cu
│   ├── omp3
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── kernel_interface.h
│   │   └── kernel.c
│   ├── omp4
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── kernel_interface.h
│   │   └── kernel.c
│   ├── omp4_clang
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── kernel_interface.h
│   │   └── kernel.c
│   └── serial
│       ├── Makefile
│       ├── kernel_interface.h
│       └── kernel.c
├── drivers
│       ├── Makefile
│       ├── kernel_interface.h
│       └── kernel_driver.c
├── kernel_interface.h
├── main.c
├── make.deps
└── make.flags
```

The makefile is configured so you would make the project like so (for omp3):

```
$ make KERNELS=omp3
```

How can I generate the Doxygen documentation for a project in this kind of structure for one type of kernel at a time?

Is it that I will need to have a Doxygen configuration for each kernel type?

Or should I add a docs build target in my makefile and then build the documentation based upon the target kernel?

Comment: You have to do some configuration for each target separately, but most of it can be identical and with a ```sed``` or similar script or with the method as described in the Paragraph "Can I configure doxygen from the command line?" it might be a bit easier. You can also experiment with environment variables in the Doxyfile and set this in your targets.

Comment: @Albert Have you got a link to that paragraph?

Comment: It is in the standard documentation of doxygen. In the online documentation see http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/faq.html#faq_cmdline or download the manual from http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/download.html